# Are there infinite prime numbers of the form $q = p^2 -2$, with $p$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For all odd primes, $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$. Via Dirichlet, we know there are an infinite number of primes of the form $q \equiv 7 \pmod 8$. Therefore there should be at least *some* primes $q = p^2 - 2$.

However, it's obvious that not *all* positive integers $n \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ are prime, and the overlap of those that are prime with integers of the form $p^2 - 2$ isn't obviously infinite.

Is there proof that there are/are not an infinite number of primes of this form?

Comment: Given how little is known about similar problems, I doubt much is known here.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A062326 is the sequence of $p$s that work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have no idea. We don't even know if there are infinitely many primes of the form $X^2 - 2$. In fact, we don't have a single example of a quadratic polynomial that we can prove takes infinitely many prime values. This is far beyond current scope.

This is closely related to [Schinzel's Hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H).

Comment: 1 or 7 mod 8 divisors by quadratic reciprocity if they exist ...